# Bitlocker lock drive on standby or switch users

Tags: encryption, windows, bitlocker

Is it possible to autolock a drive with Bitlocker when the laptop goes on standby or sleep mode?

Or when the user is changed?

I want the drive to be accessible only by one user.

Answer (score 2):

This is not what Bitlocker is for.

Full Disk Encryption (FDE) tools like Bitlocker are only meant to protect against off-line attacks. This is where the computer's operating system is not running.

Examples might be if the disk is removed and mounted in another computer, or if the computer is booted from a LiveCD or similar.

When the OS is running - which includes when the laptop is in standby - then it is the OS's job to protect the contents of the disk.

Comment: I think you're correct in regards to encrypting the **boot** drive with Bitlocker, but what if the original question was in regards to a removable USB drive, or even a secondary hard drive? I can imagine that you might want to lock that drive and remove the key from RAM when putting the computer to sleep for greater security.

Comment: Nope, same answer applies to all disks. If the OS is running, including during standby, it is responsible for protecting the disk. Bitlocker or other FDE tools are there for when the drive is unplugged and put into another device where the bad guy controls the OS.